# svn: OPTIONS of 'REPO URL: authorization failed:

Tags: svn

I am using two commands 1)svn ls with username and password 2)svn mkdir with username and password. svn ls works without any problem but svn mkdir fails with the following error message: "***svn: OPTIONS of 'REPO URL: authorization failed: 
Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge"***

Can someone please help me with this? I have googled this many times. People have reported similar problems but not exactly the same.

Comment: Same issue here: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/25646 Problem of apache conf file? Problem with the path used with `mkdir`?

Comment: Does it prompt you for username/password?  `ls` needs only `read` access while `mkdir` needs `write` access.

Comment: It does not prompt for username and password. I am sending the command with username and password. Also I noticed that it fails for few people but not for few. When I compared the command between the failed cases and not failed cases, I noticed that the password parameter is sent within quotes in failed cases and not sent within quotes for cases which passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your repo url https?

in that case please add following switch before the command.

```
svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username urname --password ******** <command>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a one-off i.e. not have to enter this every time?

Comment: @therobyouknow - create a wrapper around svn command using ant and call the task directly rather than command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Tortoise SVN installed. Go to the settings and clear the cache. It should be under "saved data". Open the repo browser, accept the certificate and save the password.

that's it !

Comment: Yep. The Tortoise SVN will clear the cache for command line SVN as well !

Comment: Not on a Linux machine it won't!

Answer (score 0):

I got this just with empty (forgotten) password, while using `--password` option.