# svn mkdir: can´t authenticate to server

Tags: svn

I have a svn repository containing a project which i can access and modify with `svn add`, `svn ci`,`svn update` etc.
I can also check out the project to a different directory

```
svn co svn+ssh://jody@my_server.my_domain.ch/home/svn_main/my_project/trunk my_project
```

I now wanted to add a new project to the repository but this failed:

```
$ svn mkdir http://my_server.my_domain.ch/home/svn_main/project2 -m "starting project2"
Authentication realm: <http://my_server.my_domain.ch:80> webdav
Password for 'jody':
```

I passed my normal user name and password (which i also use for the `svn co` command), but this is not accepted:

```
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://my_server.my_domain.ch/home/svn_main'
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of 'http://my_server.my_domain.ch/home/svn_main': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://my_server.my_domain.ch)
```

The stackoverflow post [svn: OPTIONS of 'REPO URL: authorization failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965595/svn-options-of-repo-url-authorization-failed) did not help.

What do i have to do to exactly to create this new project in the repository?

Edit: i did all the above commands while logged in as ´jody´ to  `my_server.my_domain.ch`

Comment: In your case "my_project" seems to be a repository on its own. What you are trying to do is create another repository "project2" on `svn_main` path. You need to be on the server side running `svnadmin create` command to do the same.

Comment: @SiddharthKaul I managed to create a new repository with `svnadmin create`. But when i want to fill it with data `svn import /home/jody/progs/QHG4 http://my_server.my_domain.ch/home/qhg4_svn -m "initial copy"` i get `Authentication realm: <http://aim-bigfoot.uzh.ch:80> webdav` where i can not log in with my  (or root's) credentials

Comment: Did you update the authz file for the new project??

Comment: I added 'jody = rw' in the section '[/]'of the authz file for qhg4_svn. When i now do the svn import command i get 'svn: E175003: The PROPFIND responsedif not include the requested version-controlled-configurastion value'.